# Why does HttpClient GetAsync produce a Status Code 401 Unauthorized when the same URL in the browser is successful

Tags: .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, blazor-webassembly, .net-7.0

1. I am hosting a .NET 7 Web API on an internal IIS Server.
2. From a .NET Hosted Blazor Web Assembly I am using `HttpClient.GetAsync(url)`
   to get data from the api. which produces the **Status Code** `401 Unauthorized`
   (see below).

[image: Chrome Network Tab]

3. When I paste the url (the same url used in `GetAsync`) `https://some.url.com` into the browser,
   I get data from the API.

### Questions

1. Why is this happening?
2. Can I use `GetAsync` and pass the Windows credentials to the API

I have been researching Authorization/Authentication in Blazor Web Assemblies
and haven't found anything that mentions this.

Comment: is your web-browser sending any cookies?

Comment: _"Why is this happening?"_ - that depends entirely on how your web-service's authentication and authorization schemes are set-up and you haven't shared any details of that with us, so we can't tell you.

Comment: "Can I use GetAsync and pass the Windows credentials to the Api" - what do you mean by "Windows credentials"? Are you referring to NTLM/Kerberos/Integrated auth or something else?

Comment: Thanks @Dai, I will add some details to this when I get a chance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the windows authentication inside web api and you want to call it, I suggest you could try to set the `requestMessage.SetBrowserRequestCredentials(BrowserRequestCredentials.Include);` and use it lie below:

```
var requestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage()
    {
        Method = new HttpMethod("Get"),
        RequestUri = new Uri("https://localhost:7264/WeatherForecast"),
         
    };

requestMessage.SetBrowserRequestCredentials(BrowserRequestCredentials.Include);

var response = await Http.SendAsync(requestMessage);
```

Result:

[image]